# What is the right way to ask a customer to wait till his/her food is prepared at the table?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

The problem I face when creating this sentence is that the idioms *wait on/at a table* mean *to serve food and drinks*.

How can I make a sentence where I am the cashier at a cafe and I want to ask the customer to wait next to a table?
Is *Please wait next to a table* correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "next to" or "by",  but be friendly.

> Please wait next to that table.

Is a kind of minimal sentence.  It communicates what you want to say, but it doesn't make people feel very welcome.

Why are you asking them to wait next to a table?  What are you going to do while they wait?  How long will they need to wait?

> Two lattés and one americano to go?  Okay! If you can just wait a minute over by that table, I'll bring them right over for you.

Don't worry about confusing with being a waiter.  The customers know that they aren't waiters. But don't use "wait on that table", which is the idiomatic preposition for being a waiter.

Comment: Thank you so much